# Argo Event webhook authentication with Github

Tags: github, argo-workflows, argo, argo-events

I'm trying to integrate the GitHub repo with the Argo Event Source webhook as an example (link). When the configured from the Github event returns an error.

> 'Invalid Authorization Header'.

Code:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: EventSource
metadata:
  name: ci-pipeline-webhook
spec:
  service:
    ports:
      - port: 12000
        targetPort: 12000
  webhook:
    start-pipeline:
      port: "12000"
      endpoint: /start-pipeline
      method: POST
      authSecret:
        name: my-webhook-token
        key: my-token
```

[image: API response]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a secure GitHub webhook as an event source, you will need to use the [GitHub event source type](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/eventsources/setup/github/). GitHub webhooks send a special authorization header, `X-Hub-Signature`/`X-Hub-Signature-256`, that includes as hashed value of the webhook secret. The ["regular" webhook event source](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/eventsources/setup/webhook/) expects a standard `Bearer` token with an authorization header in the form of `"Authorization: Bearer <webhook-secret>"`.

You can read more about GitHub webhook delivery headers [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#delivery-headers). You can then compare that to the Argo Events webhook event source authentication documentation [here](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/eventsources/webhook-authentication/).

There are basically two options when creating the GitHub webhook event source.

1. Provide GitHub API credentials in a Kubernetes secret so Argo Events can make the API call to GitHub to create the webhook on your behalf.
2. Omit the GitHub API credentials in the EventSource spec and create the webhook yourself either manually or through whichever means you normally create a webhook (Terraform, scripted API calls, etc).

Here is an example for the second option:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: EventSource
metadata:
  name: github-events
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  service:
    ports:
      - name: http
        port: 12000
        targetPort: 12000
  github:
    default:
      owner: my-github-org-or-username
      repository: my-github-repo-name
      webhook:
        url: https://my-argo-events-server-fqdn
        endpoint: /push
        port: "12000"
        method: POST
      events:
        - "*"
      webhookSecret:
        name: my-secret-name
        key: my-secret-key
      insecure: false
      active: true
      contentType: "json"
```